# No Wireless In Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.10

When I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10, I can't connect to wireless. The only thing I can connect to is ethernet, so please help me, What should I do?

Here is the output of the `lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A2`

```
00:19.0 ethernet controller [0200]:intel corporation 82579V Gigabit network connection [8086:1503] (rev 04) 
        subsystem: acer incorporated [ALI Device] [1025:8000] 
        Kernel driver in use : e100e

output of lsusb: 

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120 for Business
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0152 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Mass Storage Device
Bus 001 Device 040: ID 04e8:6863 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 045e:070f Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

UPDATE!

now i can connect to my wireless but i dont have internet acces + when i reboot the wireless go away please help. Thanks for the help so far :)

`iwconfig`:

```
viktor@Viktor-Dator:~$ iwconfig
usb0      no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

Comment: What is the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A2` command?

Comment: 00:19.0 ethernet controller [0200]:intel corporation 82579V Gigabit network connection [8086:1503] (rev 04) subsystem: acer incorporated [ALI Device] [1025:8000] Kernel driver in use : e100e

Answer (score 1):

Please detach the ethernet and reboot. Check to see if the wireless driver is loaded:

```
lsmod | grep rtl
```

If not, load it:

```
sudo modprobe rtl8192cu
```

Was a wireless interface created, ideally wlan0?

```
iwconfig
```

Does it scan and see your network?

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

Is the wireless switch or key combination set to enable wireless?

```
rfkill list all
```

Comment: UPDATE: i can connect to my wireless now but i dont have internet acces and when reboot the wireless go away :/

Comment: btw this is the output of iwconfig viktor@Viktor-Dator:~$ iwconfig
usb0      no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

Comment: please help, bump

Comment: My original questions remain. After reboot, is the module loaded? Does the wireless come to life if you modprobe it??

Comment: yes it's loaded after reboot and i can see my wireless but it taking a while to connect to it and when I connected I don't have internet access :/

Comment: But how can I get my Realtek wireless driver back like I had before ?